# Index Match Formula issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of SKU's from left to right columns B - X and 400 rows, not all of the cells are populated so there are plenty of blank cells.

I then have the product name in column Y (as there can be multiple colour variants and SKUs for 1 product).

On a separate tab I have all the order line details, which includes SKU, I need to append the product name on to the end of this using the first tab.

I have tried Index/Matching but it doesnt seem to be working, vlookup doesnt as I need to bring back the same column (Y) irrelevant of where it finds the match.

```
=INDEX('All Lines'!Y3:Y428,match(*Product SKU*,'All Lines'!B3:X428,0))
```

All lines is my first tab, with the product SKU coming from the tab with the order details

Expectation is the product name will be output (which is in column Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I misinterpreted your question I think. Are you looking for a certain value that can be anywhere in the matrix `B3:X428` and return the row to the `INDEX()` row parameter?

In that case you could try to incorporate `SUMPRODUCT()` within the `INDEX()` row parameter like so (simplified):

[image]

The formula in G2:

```
=INDEX(D2:D9,SUMPRODUCT((A2:C9=G1)*ROW(A2:C9))-1)
```

Comment: ah thank you, the formula does work, but it strangely pulls back the product name of the product below the one I am after?? 

so e.g. on your picture the output would be product7 even though the match is on product6? @JvdV

Comment: @JordanMynes, You didn't account for the two rows above your data, whereas my data starts in row 2, yours effectively starts at row 3. To compensate for that you have to change the 1 at the end of the formula to a 2.